# How to select the row that is the last row of a group in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataFrame like this:

| first | second | third | fourth | fifth | sixth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 1 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 2 |
| aaa | 3 | 4 | 6 | 1 | 3 |
| bbb | 5 | 6 | 9 | 4 | 5 |
| bbb | 7 | 8 | 12 | 1 | 7 |
| ccc | 9 | 10 | 15 | 5 | 11 |
| ccc | 11 | 12 | 18 | 9 | 13 |
| ddd | 13 | 14 | 21 | 2 | 17 |

I have used groupby('first') and calculate the sum of sixth column in every group.

Now I want to add the sum results into the dataFrame in a new column sum_of_sixth.

I don't want to fill the seventh column with sum results because that would make no sense.

What I want to do is locate the last row of each group, and add the sum value in the sum_of_sixth column of that row.

For example, the resulting dataFrame would look like this:

| first | second | third | fourth | fifth | sixth | sum_of_sixth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 1 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 2 |  |
| aaa | 3 | 4 | 6 | 1 | 3 | 5 |
| bbb | 5 | 6 | 9 | 4 | 5 |  |
| bbb | 7 | 8 | 12 | 1 | 7 | 12 |
| ccc | 9 | 10 | 15 | 5 | 11 |  |
| ccc | 11 | 12 | 18 | 9 | 13 | 24 |
| ddd | 13 | 14 | 21 | 2 | 17 | 17 |

I tried concat and iteration, but none seems working as I wished.

I think after locate the specific row, add the sum result to a new column would be easy.

Just create a new column filled with nan and proceed from there, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use [`groupby.transform('sum')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and to assign only to the last row with [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with help of [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
df.loc[~df['first'].duplicated(keep='last'),
       'sum_of_sixth'] = df.groupby('first')['sixth'].transform('sum')
```

An alternative with [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html) and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
s = df.groupby('first')['sixth'].sum()
m = ~df['first'].duplicated(keep='last')

df.loc[m, 'sum_of_sixth'] = df.loc[m, 'first'].map(s)
```

Output:

```
  first  second  third  fourth  fifth  sixth  sum_of_sixth
0   aaa       1      2       3      3      2           NaN
1   aaa       3      4       6      1      3           5.0
2   bbb       5      6       9      4      5           NaN
3   bbb       7      8      12      1      7          12.0
4   ccc       9     10      15      5     11           NaN
5   ccc      11     12      18      9     13          24.0
6   ddd      13     14      21      2     17          17.0
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Thanks for the help!